# Is there a maximum radius for the geocode parameter in the twitter search API?

Tags: twitter

The twitter search API documentation https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search shows the following example URL to search for all tweets within a radius of 1km around -22.912214,-43.230182:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=&geocode=-22.912214,-43.230182,1km&lang=pt&result_type=recent
```

If I would instead like to search for all tweets within a radius of 100000km like

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=&geocode=-22.912214,-43.230182,100000km&lang=pt&result_type=recent
```

would that mean I would get all tweets from the whole world? Or is there a maximum radius that can be given to the twitter search API?

Comment: How the hell is this not answered?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be 1 mile.

```
In [20]: len(api.search(geocode="-22.912214,-43.230182,1mi"))
Out[20]: 15

In [21]: len(api.search(geocode="-22.912214,-43.230182,10000km"))
Out[21]: 15

In [22]: len(api.search(geocode="-22.912214,-43.230182,1.3km"))
Out[22]: 14
```

Comment: This answer did not set the "count" parameter to allow for more than 15 results

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the limit is 25mi. I've read it in several places, but nothing in the official docs.
The most relevant place talking about this 25mi limit is the Gnip offical page:
http://support.gnip.com/articles/filtering-twitter-data-by-location.html